# Flask and Stripe Payment: 400 Bad Request from API call

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, flask, stripe-payments

I am trying to send a JSON file from my Frontend to Flask where the JSON file is the line_items for the Stripe checkout session. However, I keep getting the following error:
400 Bad Request: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'.

I have checked to make sure the content I am sending is in JSON format and am at a loss. Any help is appreciated!

**payment.py**

```
def checkout():
    try:
        request_data = request.get_json()
        line_items = []
        print(request_data)
        for item in request_data:
            line_items.append({
                'price': item['price'],
                'quantity': item['quantity']
            })

        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            line_items=line_items,
            mode='payment',
            success_url=DOMAIN + '/success.html',
            cancel_url=DOMAIN + '/cancel.html',
        )
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

    return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

**Checkout.html**

```
  <body>
    <form action="/checkout" method="POST">
      <button onclick="checkout()">Checkout</button>
    </form>
  </body>
```

**checkout.html Within script tag**

```
      const lineItems = [
        {
          //  Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
          price: "price_1MmYqVHbLz6qKWZ5hrkATlX",
          quantity: 1,
        },
        {
          //  Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
          price: "price_1MmYGHHbLz6qKWZ5rKteRTy",
          quantity: 2,
        },
      ];

      fetch("/checkout", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(lineItems),
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Postman calls to the endpoint does not give bad gateway request, I believe that the Form is sending in form-data which leads to the Bad Gateway Request

Comment: Looks like `<form action="/checkout" method="POST">` make a request to `/checkout` directly instead of invoking the script, then to server. I'd recommend following the guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart?lang=python) to implement Checkout Session with python server.